# How to apply a GCP Monitoring Alert Policy to specific GCE instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Let us say, I have a Terraform script that declares two Google Compute Engine instances 'instance-1' and 'instance-2' and furthermore two alerting policies 'policy-1' and 'policy-2'. I have checked that it runs fine and that the resources are deployed accordingly in my test project in the GCP.

Apparently, all alerting policies are automatically applied to all GCE instances in the projects. At least, I get alerting emails for both policies for each instance. But how can I make it so that 'policy-1' is only applied to 'instance-1' and the same for 'policy-2' and 'instance-2'?

I have tried setting the metadata for the 'instance-1' like this.

```
  metadata {
    google-monitoring-enabled = "true"
    policy-1-id = "test-policy-2"
  }
```

Analogously for the other instance and policy. But still I get alerting mails for both policies on both instances.

Comment: All you need to do is to create two separate alert policies and in each compute engine vm definition you need to mention respective alert policies in the metadata section.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a filter with the "resource.labels.instance_id" of each VM in the different alert Policies.

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy_instance01" { 
  display_name = "My Alert Policy Instance 01"
  conditions {
    display_name = "test condition instance 01"
    condition_threshold {
      filter     = ""resource.labels.instance_id=\"[ID_INSTANCE_01]\""
```

...